# descargar Build Tools 26.0.2 para Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

Deseo descargar Build Tools versión 26.0.2 pero no me deja descargarlo por mi posición geográfica (me encuentro en Cuba) en el SDK Manager.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado a instalarlo desde `SDK Tools` en Android Studio, [como explica la documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)?.

Comment: Si eres de Cuba seria buena idea agregaras esa info. @Yikel200

Comment: En File -> Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies -> + -> Library Dependency. También puedes intentarlo desde ahí.

Comment: Soy de Cuba por eso es que no me deja insatalarlo !! @ Jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

Hola soy de Cuba tambien, para descargar esa version lo haces conectandote mediante un vpn o proxy, con este link:

Para linux: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r26.0.2-linux.zip

Para windows: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r26.0.2-windows.zip

si no sabes como hacerlo dime para dejarte el build en dropbox

Comment: Gracias, ya pude atualizar el SDK , de que parte eres !!

Comment: de Matanzas, saludos

Comment: Hola @DanielPiadAldazabal actualmente continuas descargando manualmente, podrías ayudar a un miembro de la comunidad?

Comment: @Jorgesys uso el sdk, pero imagino que descargar manual no tenga problema, conectandose a un proxy o VPN si esta en un lugar donde no deja como por ej Cuba. En lo que pueda ayudar me dices.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino te encuentras en Cuba, en este caso debes configurar tu Android Studio para trabajar offline, debes no permitir que Android Studio tenga conexión a internet, entra a los `Settings` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Debes configurar que use una distribución local de Gradle.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este articulo en español es excelente:

[Preparando entorno de desarrollo Android Studio para Cuba](http://jorgen.cubava.cu/2016/09/13/curso-1ra-parte-preparando-entorno-de-desarrollo-android-studio-para-cuba/)

Comment: si soy de Cuba, mi Android Estudio es la version 3.0.1. Por lo que he buscado es un bug en este IDE, todos los repararon simplemente desargando el Buil Tool 26.0.2 por el SDK Manager